# Writing directly to the 16550A serial port from kernel module

Tags: c, linux-device-driver, uart

I need to write directly to the serial port (I'm trying to debug a hang up in a irq handler, and thus want to write to the serial port without going via the normal driver which I assume uses interrupts).

Anyway, I have written this small piece of code to try to test writing to the serial port.
I have executed

```
setserial /dev/ttyS0 uart none
```

to release the port from the normal driver.

The code:

```
#define PORT 0x3f8

static int test_module_init(void) {
        if(request_region(0x3f8, 5, "test_module") == NULL) {
                printk("<1> Failed to request_region\n");
        } else {
                printk("<1> Request region success!\n");
                outb(0x00, PORT + 1);    // Disable all interrupts
                outb(0x80, PORT + 3);    // Enable DLAB (set baud rate divisor)
                outb(0x01, PORT + 0);    // Set divisor to 1 (lo byte) 115200 baud
                outb(0x00, PORT + 1);    //                  (hi byte)
                outb(0x03, PORT + 3);    // 8 bits, no parity, one stop bit

                outb(0x00, PORT + 2);    // Disable fifo
                outb('a', PORT);
                outb('\n', PORT);
                printk("<1> Sent a\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

It succeeds in requesting the region, but I get no data over the serial port. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I have tried various setttings (fifo enable/disable etc) but with no luck.